# how to make a faked Android/ios http post request from desktop

Tags: android, ios, http, request

Is there a way to make a faked http post request from desktop, but  looks like from a real iOS/Android hardware(i.e.  iPhone 5s 6.7 square inches, Samsung Galaxy 5.1-inch)?

I have no clue what’s the difference between the requests from deferent device(header,body...), how can a server know where the request from?

Thanks a lot. Merry Christmas.

Comment: from meta data ... analyze the requests ... and no, "User-Agent" header is not the only one possibilities ...  fx: some server frameworks get header's order to the count, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is User-Agent.
You should easily be able to change it in your request, whatever the request is.

Answer (score 0):

When your browser makes a request, among different headers there is a "User-Agent" header containing details of your browser and your OS. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I would use a REST Client like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) for Chrome to send a POST Request along with the "User-Agent" string of my choice.

You can also use Chrome Developer Tools (opens with ctrl+shift+i in Windows) for the emulation feature that lets you emulate among a variety of devices. More info about that [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode).
With the emulation method in Chrome you can easily hit your server/webpage like you would normally by typing the URL in your browser (GET requests) from any of the available devices.